# How to create a folder and write N files into folder in Python in Windows & again read those N files into Python

Tags: python-3.x

Here I am trying to take `dirname` from `file_path` and add `new_folder` then write the files into the folder.

```
dirctry = os.path.dirname(file_path)
    toolSharePath = os.path.abspath(dirctry)
    final_directory = os.path.join(toolSharePath, r'new_folder')
    if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
       os.makedirs(final_directory,exist_ok=True)
    with open(final_directory, "w") as f:
        f.write("data")
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: code which i have posted is working for creating folder in current directory ,but it is not working for inserting data files into folder.